# Comprobar dos booleanos y recibir dos retornos

Tags: javascript

Hola el caso es que necesito que las dos if se comprueben.

Pero no logro que pase del primero, porque, al ser verdadero, que en 'a' los números son menores a 9, corta el proceso y devuelve true. No logro que compruebe que igual existe un numero menor a 2.

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3];

function buscar (fn){
    for(let i = 0; i < fn.length; i++){
        if(fn[i] <= 9) return true;
        if(fn[i] < 2) return false;
    }
};

console.log(buscar(a));
```

Comment: es porque `return` finaliza la iteración, puedes ir asignando a una variable para despues tratar el elemento [fiddle de ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/6vqwgesx/1/)

Comment: Primero, una función de javascript solo puede retornar 1 valor. Por lo tanto, eso de `recibir dos retornos` no es posible. Segundo, por favor lee [example] para que entendamos qué estas buscando con tus condiciones. Qué resultado esperas obtener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devolver dos valores diferentes no es buena idea, lo que puede hacer es colocarlos dentro de alguna estructura y así comparar con lo que se requiere. Puede hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
let unOrderedList = [1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 2, 10, 4, 7]

function buscar(fn) {

  const lessThanTwo = fn.filter(element => element < 2)
  const lessThanNine = fn.filter(element => element <= 9)
  return {
    lessThanTwo,
    lessThanNine
  }
}

console.log(buscar(unOrderedList))
```

Comment: No se olvide de colocar el flecha arriba ya que ayuda a la reputación de la respuesta. Son unos triángulos (uno hacía arriba y otro hacia abajo) y en el medio está un número (en este momento está en 0.

Answer (score 0):

En todo caso entiendo, que buscas obtener cuando un número es menor a 2 (false) y cuando es menor a 9 pero mayor que 2 (true), para ello podrías verificar la primera condición dentro de la segunda, así se ejecutara también, pero toma en cuenta que no se puede obtener dos resultados de una función, tiene que existir una prioridad en tus condiciones para retornar siempre un solo resultado

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3];

function buscar (fn){
    for(let i = 0; i < fn.length; i++){
        if(fn[i] <= 9) 
        {
          if(fn[i] < 2) return false;
          return true;
        }
    }
};

console.log(buscar(a));
```

Comment: Gracias voy a intentarlo como me sugieres.